# For loop to sum multiple numeric values in dataframe: getting only NULL value returned, R 3.2.1, RStudio 0.99.467, Windows 7

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I am new to R (and programming in general), and I am trying to analyze my first dataset using the language.

I have added new columns to designed to score multiple choice questions in a data frame. I defined the data in these new columns as numeric, with correct answers being assigned a value of 1 and incorrect answers being assigned a value of 0. There are some NA values within each new column added, due to study participants refusing to answer some questions.

Next, to calculate an aggregate score, I wrote a for loop to sum the values across the 10 columns and put the answer into a new column, PAKKD_AK.

**However, when I print the new column, I am getting an answer of "NULL". No errors are coming up from the code, so I'm not sure what to do to get the code to return a number that ignores NA values when calculating the answer. I would appreciate feedback for ways to redo the code, so that I get a numeric value returned instead of NULL.**

My code is below:

```
#Read Data
data=read.csv('AnemiaRiskCommunicat_DATA_2015-09-01_1011.csv')

## subsets data to include only PAKKD and demographics columns
PAKKD_dem <- data[, c(1:54, 113:171, 352)]

##makes new variables and adds them as new columns to score if PAKKD MC actual knowledge questions are correct
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD9_score <- as.numeric(ifelse(PAKKD_dem$pakkd_pre_anemiaiswhen == "2", 1, 0)) 
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD10_score <- as.numeric(ifelse(PAKKD_dem$pakkd_pre_anemiadevelops == "4", 1, 0))
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD11_score <- as.numeric(ifelse(PAKKD_dem$pakkd_pre_anemiamorecommon == "4", 1, 0))
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD12_score <- as.numeric(ifelse(PAKKD_dem$pakkd_pre_anemiamaymake == "1", 1, 0))
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD13_score <- as.numeric(ifelse(PAKKD_dem$pakkd_pre_anemiacanhurt == "1", 1, 0))
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD14_score <- as.numeric(ifelse(PAKKD_dem$pakkd_pre_treatmentsanemia == "4", 1, 0))
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD15_score <- as.numeric(ifelse(PAKKD_dem$pakkd_pre_hemoglobinnohigher == "11", 1, 0))
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD16_score <- as.numeric(ifelse(PAKKD_dem$pakkd_pre_hgbtoohighhurts == "3", 1, 0))
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD17_score <- as.numeric(ifelse(PAKKD_dem$pakkd_pre_epoiswhat == "2", 1, 0))
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD18_score <- as.numeric(ifelse(PAKKD_dem$pakkd_pre_whatdoesepodo == "3", 1, 0))
PAKKD_dem$line_number <-  c(1:294)

##makes new variable that calculates total AK MC score per patient, per time point
PAKKD_dem$PAKKD_AK <- for (i in PAKKD_dem$line_number) {sum(PAKKD_dem[, 115:124])}
```

Here is what it returns:

```
> PAKKD_dem$PAKKD_AK
NULL
```

If I try this permutation of only looking at summing the variables across one row, I get the following result:

```
> PAKKD_AK <- sum(1, PAKKD_dem$PAKKD9_score, PAKKD_dem$PAKKD10_score, PAKKD_dem$PAKKD11_score, PAKKD_dem$PAKKD12_score, PAKKD_dem$PAKKD13_score, PAKKD_dem$PAKKD14_score, PAKKD_dem$PAKKD15_score, PAKKD_dem$PAKKD16_score, PAKKD_dem$PAKKD17_score, PAKKD_dem$PAKKD18_score, rm.na=TRUE)
> 
> PAKKD_AK
[1] NA
```

Any help/suggestions about how to help me see a number instead of NA and/or NULL values are appreciated.

Comment: Since you're a begginer, you should look for begginer courses. Your foor loop doesn't make sense as it does the exact same things `n` times, since `i` isn't in the code. Also you shouldn't use for loops to return a result, the more appropriate solution would be an *apply family function. Finally, there's probably a better general approach to the problem given how repetitive your code looks.

Comment: I think that `PAKKD_dem$PAKKD_AK <- for (i in PAKKD_dem$line_number) {sum(PAKKD_dem[i, 115:124], na.rm=T)}` will give you something better than NAs. `rm.na=TRUE` is not the right way to use it. Try your last permutation using `na.rm` instead.